# Add locale in variable for command

Tags: bash, variable, command, locale

I'm trying to call a command from a variable in a script with a specific locale, example :

```
$ myYTDL="LANG=C.UTF-8 youtube-dl --get-filename"
```

but each time I try and call it in the script, I get :

```
$ $myYTDL $url
LANG=C.UTF-8: command not found
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: @kusalananda I thought my question was one specific to the assignment before the command in the variable. I didn't know this could be solved by calling the `eval` builtin :

`myYTDL="eval LANG=C.UTF-8 youtube-dl"`

Thanks bro :)

Comment: That's definitely the wrong take-home message from that question. Use a shell function or put the command into an array.